# Swift: one webview for multiple classes

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Is it possible to use one webview and call multiple classes to it using Swift?

I am trying to call JavaScript from an UIAlertController that was created in a separate class for handling callbacks. I am finding that I can only do this when I run

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    //This calls the JavaScript but does so automatically and only from the ViewController where the webview is created.        
    Webview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("CallToJS(true)")

}
```

I found I can also get it to work when I create an @IBAction for an object and put a UIAlertController inside in the other class with the callback handler.